# NFC app doesn't detect tag on specific phones

Tags: android, nfc

I am forced to support some android app which works with NFC hardware. The main usage scenario is phone put closely to the antenna of the  ST M24SR tag (ISO/IEC 14443 Type A compatible NFC forum tag type 4), then tag content is read with this app, modified and written back to the tag. It works perfect with Samsung S-series phones and I remember it did worked with some LG Nexus too. It even works properly with blackberry Z10, which only emulates android. But there is a bunch of NFC-powered phones (Oneplus 5T, HTC one A9, Honor 9 lite), that don't work properly: the app doesn't launch, there is even no sound signal to see, if the tag was actually read. Can anybody give me any advice on what steps should I take, to localize and fix this nasty bug? 
Maybe there are some tricks for debugging NFC apps without actually having troublesome phone, because I am pretty sure, that my employer will not buy each of those for me. 
Does anyone experienced situations, when any other apps (payment systems?) prevents your app from working properly?
Here is manifest for you to check if I missed something:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ua.dct.smartaccesskey">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:name="AnalyticsApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/main_icon_draw"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="accesscard" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".QRScannerActivity"
        android:label="@string/scanQrCode"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Also here scanned tag content, for me it seems to be totally legit:

```
** TagInfo scan (version 4.24.4) 2018-10-02 15:14:24 **
Report Type: External
-- IC INFO ------------------------------
# IC manufacturer:
STMicroelectronics SA
# IC type:
M24SR02-Y
# NFC Forum NDEF-compliant tag:
Type 4 Tag
# Application information:
Type 4 Tag v2 application present
Type 4 Tag v1 application present
-- NDEF ------------------------------
# NFC data set information:
NDEF message containing 1 record
Current message size: 37 bytes
Maximum message size: 254 bytes
NFC data set access: Read & Write
# Record #1: 
URI record:
Type Name Format: NFC Forum well-known type
Short Record
type: "U"
protocol field: [none]
URI field: accesscard://SOMEDOOR_//4066183A
Payload length: 33 bytes
Payload data:
[00] 00 61 63 63 65 73 73 63 61 72 64 3A 2F 2F 53 4F |.accesscard://SO|
[10] 4D 45 44 4F 4F 52 5F 2F 2F 34 30 36 36 31 38 33 |MEDOOR_//4066183|
[20] 41                                              |A               |
# NDEF message:
[00] D1 01 21 55 00 61 63 63 65 73 73 63 61 72 64 3A |..!U.accesscard:|
[10] 2F 2F 53 4F 4D 45 44 4F 4F 52 5F 2F 2F 34 30 36 |//SOMEDOOR_//406|
[20] 36 31 38 33 41                                  |6183A           |
```

Comment: I'm owner of OnePlus 5T, and NFC sucks on it. NFC antenna is just above the camera (thin plastic line) and is very weak, I think it's common problem for devices with steel back. Try placing tag at the top, this may work

Comment: @DimaRostopira we tried it, still no luck.

Comment: Does this devices run Oreo or later? I don't see `NDEF_DISCOVERED` in [implicit broadcast exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)

Comment: (1) Check if NFC is actually enabled on the device. You can do this programmatically using `NfcAdapter.isEnabled()`. But to be honest I assume that you already checked this and NFC is on.

Comment: (2) In that case, if the tag is not detected (and there is no sound at all), there's typically not much you can do on the software side. This is usually an indication that the phone and the tag don't interface well (due to issues with antenna tuning, and band communication over the RF interface in general).

Comment: @MichaelRoland your assumption is correct. That check is in place.

Comment: Have you tried with other NFC utilities Apps from Google play to check if you can connect with the devices you are referring? There is a tool from [ST](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.st.st25nfc) or from [NXP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite). Good luck!

Comment: I don't have this phone nearby, but users did tried on my request. Phone ignores tag, no matter which application it runs.

Comment: Hi @Vadimchik I have the same issue here with a M24SR64-Y chip. Read operations are running well except with some devices (mainly Samsungs for the moment) when Android is more recent than 7.0. Did you manage to find a workaround solution? Because, on my side, I'm mainly blaming the ST chip. It should work with all Android devices no matter the operating system version!